# The visual studio F# interactive window keeps not opening in current directory

Tags: visual-studio, f#, f#-interactive

So I want to work a little bit in the interactive window in visual studio, to take a look at some F#.
Now View>other windows>F# interactive

In order to load my file I then type

```
>#load "Distance.fs";;
```

It is important to mention that Distance.fs is the current file that I am standing on.
however now, I get this error:
[image]

It looks like it keeps looking in the wrong directory, and it keeps doing this across different files and projects. Why does this happen? Is there any way I can configure VS to always open the interactive windows on the currently open directory

Comment: Does this happen when you write the line into a script file and then sent to interactive with Alt-Enter? I recommend you always do that and **never** type directly into FSI. This has many benefits including auto-complete, live type-checking, syntax highlighting, not having to type `;;` etc.

Comment: It happens when i have the file open in the ide, and open interactive window through the toolbar. Im not quite sure what you mean by "write the line into a script file"

Comment: Create an FSX file, write some code in it, select the code and press Alt-Enter. That will send the code to FSI as if you typed it there. Or if you don't select any code it will just send the current line.

Comment: Here's a video that demonstrates it for VS Code, just ignore the IDE specific stuff: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QeZ5eXWBbsI

Comment: thank you, but I am already able to do this in vs code, it is just vs that is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FSI defaults its current directory to whatever %TEMP% is and just needs a little help. Create a scratch script (as @TheQuickBrownFox suggested), and put your #load statement in there. Above that, add

```
open System

Environment.CurrentDirectory <- __SOURCE_DIRECTORY__
```

Highlight those two lines and press Alt-Enter to tell FSI to change to the script's current directory, then your #load statement should work (if needed, adjust your path, for example if you create a separate scripts folder, then maybe you now need #load "../Distance.fs", etc.

Comment: thank you, any guide on how to create the sratch scripts?

Comment: Just add an F# script to your project. When I say "scratch", I just mean you might not really care about whatever you put in there, you just use the script to send stuff to FSI. (JetBrains Rider actually has a place to hold "scratch" stuff so you don't have to agonize about whether you should check these kinds of scripts into source control).